# Why is my Jetpack Compose Navigation App Stopping?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack-navigation

I'm practicing Compose navigation. I made an App that displays a row with images, *on what I call SuccessScreen*, when a particular item is clicked it navigates to a destination containing more information/ Details, *on what I called SuccessInfoScreen*. And to do this I used Navigation compose `Arugments`. I basically did this by benchmarking the [Android Developers Rally Compose](https://developer.android.com/codelabs/jetpack-compose-navigation?continue=https%3A%2F%2Fdeveloper.android.com%2Fcourses%2Fpathways%2Fjetpack-compose-for-android-developers-3%23codelab-https%3A%2F%2Fdeveloper.android.com%2Fcodelabs%2Fjetpack-compose-navigation#6), including the Tab Row feature.

*Please show some understanding and patience, I'm kinda new the to this.*

But the problem is **when I click on an item to navigate to the `SuccessScreen` the App stops.** I don't know what's causing it or how to fix it, it started when I made changes to the `SuccessScreen`.

So I believe the problem was coming from `SuccessScreen` (remember, I said this was the destination I'm navigating from).

I'm going to post the codes, of the SuccessScreen, that gives error and not the SuccessInfoScreen, as I don't what the code to be more lengthy.

Please understand that I arranged the code, in multiple composables, in this format;
`FirstBodyElement` -> `FirstBodyRow` ---------> `SuccessContentScreen` 
`SecondBodyElement` -> `SecondBodyGrid` ------> `SuccessContentScreen`

And Finally I call `SuccessContentScreen` on the `SuccessScreen`.

Please I'll talk about the changes I made, in time, as I think it has something to do with it.

FirstBodyElement;

```
@Composable
fun FirstBodyElement(
    successInfo: SuccessInfoData,
    onSuccessCardClick: (SuccessInfoData) -> Unit
) {
    Column(
        horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally,
        modifier = Modifier
            .clickable { onSuccessCardClick(successInfo) }
    ) {
        Image(
            painter = painterResource(successInfo.successInfoImageId),
            contentDescription = null,
            contentScale = ContentScale.Crop,
            modifier = Modifier
                .size(88.dp)
                .clip(RoundedCornerShape(16.dp))
        )

        Text(
            text = successInfo.title,
            style = MaterialTheme.typography.h3,
            modifier = Modifier.paddingFromBaseline(
                top = 24.dp, bottom = 8.dp
            )
        )
    }
}
```

FirstBodyRow;

```
@Composable
fun FirstBodyRow(
    successInfo: List<SuccessInfoData>,
    onSuccessCardClick: (SuccessInfoData) -> Unit,
) {
    LazyRow(
        horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.spacedBy(8.dp),
        contentPadding = PaddingValues(horizontal = 16.dp),
        modifier = Modifier
    ) {
        items(
            items = successInfo,
            itemContent = {
                FirstBodyElement(it, onSuccessCardClick)
            }
        )
    }
}
```

This (`FirstBodyRow`) was where I started making the changes, I made SuccessInfoData into List (parameter of FirstBodyRow), so it becomes `successInfo: List<SuccessInfoData>`, And Of course I did the same for `SecondBodyGrid`, `SuccessContentScreen` and the `SuccessScreen`. I did this because the item in `FirstBodyRow`and `SecondBodyGrid` was showing error, `error: None of the following functions can be called with the arguments supplied.`, But when I pass the parameter as List, this error goes away.

SecondBodyElement;

```
@Composable
fun SecondBodyElement(
    successInfo: SuccessInfoData,
    onSuccessCardClick: (SuccessInfoData) -> Unit
) {
    Surface(
        shape = MaterialTheme.shapes.small,
        modifier = Modifier
            .clickable { onSuccessCardClick(successInfo) }
    ) {
        Row(
            verticalAlignment = Alignment.CenterVertically,
            modifier = Modifier
                .width(192.dp)
        ) {
            Image(
                painter = painterResource(successInfo.successInfoImageId),
                contentDescription = null,
                contentScale = ContentScale.Crop,
                modifier = Modifier
                    .size(56.dp)
            )
            Text(
                text = successInfo.title,
                style = MaterialTheme.typography.h3,
                modifier = Modifier.padding(horizontal = 16.dp)
            )
        }

    }
}
```

SecondyBodyGrid;

```
@Composable
fun SecondBodyGrid(
    successInfo: List<SuccessInfoData>,
    onSuccessCardClick: (SuccessInfoData) -> Unit = {},
) {
    LazyHorizontalGrid(
        rows = GridCells.Fixed(2),
        contentPadding = PaddingValues(horizontal = 16.dp),
        horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.spacedBy(8.dp),
        verticalArrangement = Arrangement.spacedBy(8.dp),
        modifier = Modifier.height(120.dp)
    ) {
        items(
            items = successInfo,
            itemContent = {
                SecondBodyElement(it, onSuccessCardClick)
            }
        )
    }
}
```

SuccessContentScreen;

```
@Composable
fun SuccessContentScreen(
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
    onSuccessCardClick: (List<SuccessInfoData>) -> Unit,
    accountType: String? = SuccessInfoModel.successInfoModelList.first().title
) {

    //val successInfo = remember(accountType) { SuccessInfoModel.getSuccessInfo(accountType) }
    val successInfo = remember(accountType) { SuccessInfoModel.successInfoModelList }

    Column(
        modifier
            .verticalScroll(rememberScrollState())
            .padding(vertical = 16.dp)
    ) {
        SuccessQuote()
        SuccessTitleSection(title = R.string.women_between_18_39) {
            FirstBodyRow(successInfo) { onSuccessCardClick(successInfo) }
        }
        SuccessTitleSection(title = R.string.women_40) {
            SecondBodyGrid(successInfo) { onSuccessCardClick(successInfo) }
        }
    }
}
```

And Finally SuccessScreen;

```
@Composable
fun SuccessScreen(onSuccessCardClick: (List<SuccessInfoData>) -> Unit) {
    SuccessContentScreen(onSuccessCardClick = onSuccessCardClick)
}
```

I also change a function in my NavHost to List

```
private fun NavHostController.navigateToSuccessInfoScreen(accountType: List<SuccessInfoData>) {
    this.navigateSingleTopTo("${SuccessInfoDestination.route}/$accountType")
}
```

which I'm suppose to use to navigate to the SuccessInfoScreen.

For more information I'll add this;

```
....
    fun getSuccessInfo(accountName: String?): SuccessInfoData {
            return successInfoModelList.first { it.title == accountName }
        }
....
```

This is defined in the SuccessScreen Data/Model (I put them together) file. And I copied it from the Android Developer's Rally App.

Please I know this is a lot, and I appreciate your patience so far. No information is too small.

Thanks for your help in advance. If you need any Information I'm more than happy to provide it, Thanks.

Edit;

ADDING ERROR FROM RUN;

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.think_healthy.keto, PID: 32069
    java.util.NoSuchElementException: Collection contains no element matching the predicate.
        at com.think_healthy.keto.model.SuccessInfoModel.getSuccessInfo(SuccessInfoModel.kt:120)
        at com.think_healthy.keto.ui.screens.success.SuccessInfoScreenKt.SuccessInfoDetails(SuccessInfoScreen.kt:39)
        at com.think_healthy.keto.ui.screens.success.SuccessInfoScreenKt.DisplaySuccessInfo(SuccessInfoScreen.kt:83)
        at com.think_healthy.keto.ui.screens.success.SuccessInfoScreenKt.SuccessInfoScreen(SuccessInfoScreen.kt:31)
        at com.think_healthy.keto.ComposableSingletons$KetoNavHostKt$lambda-3$1.invoke(KetoNavHost.kt:75)
        at com.think_healthy.keto.ComposableSingletons$KetoNavHostKt$lambda-3$1.invoke(KetoNavHost.kt:69)
        at androidx.compose.runtime.internal.ComposableLambdaImpl.invoke(ComposableLambda.jvm.kt:116)
        at androidx.compose.runtime.internal.ComposableLambdaImpl.invoke(ComposableLambda.jvm.kt:34)
        at androidx.navigation.compose.NavHostKt$NavHost$4$2.invoke(NavHost.kt:163)
        at androidx.navigation.compose.NavHostKt$NavHost$4$2.invoke(NavHost.kt:162)
        at androidx.compose.runtime.internal.ComposableLambdaImpl.invoke(ComposableLambda.jvm.kt:107)
        at androidx.compose.runtime.internal.ComposableLambdaImpl.invoke(ComposableLambda.jvm.kt:34)
        at androidx.compose.runtime.CompositionLocalKt.CompositionLocalProvider(CompositionLocal.kt:228)
        at androidx.compose.runtime.saveable.SaveableStateHolderImpl.SaveableStateProvider(SaveableStateHolder.kt:84)
        at androidx.navigation.compose.NavBackStackEntryProviderKt.SaveableStateProvider(NavBackStackEntryProvider.kt:60)
        at androidx.navigation.compose.NavBackStackEntryProviderKt.access$SaveableStateProvider(NavBackStackEntryProvider.kt:1)
        at androidx.navigation.compose.NavBackStackEntryProviderKt$LocalOwnersProvider$1.invoke(NavBackStackEntryProvider.kt:52)
        at androidx.navigation.compose.NavBackStackEntryProviderKt$LocalOwnersProvider$1.invoke(NavBackStackEntryProvider.kt:51)
        at androidx.compose.runtime.internal.ComposableLambdaImpl.invoke(ComposableLambda.jvm.kt:107)
        at androidx.compose.runtime.internal.ComposableLambdaImpl.invoke(ComposableLambda.jvm.kt:34)
        at androidx.compose.runtime.CompositionLocalKt.CompositionLocalProvider(CompositionLocal.kt:228)
        at androidx.navigation.compose.NavBackStackEntryProviderKt.LocalOwnersProvider(NavBackStackEntryProvider.kt:47)
        at androidx.navigation.compose.NavHostKt$NavHost$4.invoke(NavHost.kt:162)
        at androidx.navigation.compose.NavHostKt$NavHost$4.invoke(NavHost.kt:141)
        at androidx.compose.runtime.internal.ComposableLambdaImpl.invoke(ComposableLambda.jvm.kt:116)
        at androidx.compose.runtime.internal.ComposableLambdaImpl.invoke(ComposableLambda.jvm.kt:34)
        at androidx.compose.animation.CrossfadeKt$Crossfade$5$1.invoke(Crossfade.kt:133)
        at androidx.compose.animation.CrossfadeKt$Crossfade$5$1.invoke(Crossfade.kt:128)
        at androidx.compose.runtime.internal.ComposableLambdaImpl.invoke(ComposableLambda.jvm.kt:107)
        at androidx.compose.runtime.internal.ComposableLambdaImpl.invoke(ComposableLambda.jvm.kt:34)
        at androidx.compose.animation.CrossfadeKt.Crossfade(Crossfade.kt:142)
        at androidx.compose.animation.CrossfadeKt.Crossfade(Crossfade.kt:73)
        at androidx.navigation.compose.NavHostKt.NavHost(NavHost.kt:141)
        at androidx.navigation.compose.NavHostKt.NavHost(NavHost.kt:67)
        at com.think_healthy.keto.KetoNavHostKt.KetoNavHost(KetoNavHost.kt:22)
        at com.think_healthy.keto.ComposableSingletons$MainActivityKt$lambda-2$1$2.invoke(MainActivity.kt:54)
        at com.think_healthy.keto.ComposableSingletons$MainActivityKt$lambda-2$1$2.invoke(MainActivity.kt:53)
        at androidx.compose.runtime.internal.ComposableLambdaImpl.invoke(ComposableLambda.jvm.kt:116)
        at androidx.compose.runtime.internal.ComposableLambdaImpl$invoke$1.invoke(ComposableLambda.jvm.kt:127)
        at androidx.compose.runtime.internal.ComposableLambdaImpl$invoke$1.invoke(ComposableLambda.jvm.kt:127)
E/AndroidRuntime:     at androidx.compose.runtime.RecomposeScopeImpl.compose(RecomposeScopeImpl.kt:145)
        at androidx.compose.runtime.ComposerImpl.recomposeToGroupEnd(Composer.kt:2367)
        at androidx.compose.runtime.ComposerImpl.skipCurrentGroup(Composer.kt:2634)
        at androidx.compose.runtime.ComposerImpl$doCompose$2$5.invoke(Composer.kt:3250)
        at androidx.compose.runtime.ComposerImpl$doCompose$2$5.invoke(Composer.kt:3228)
        at androidx.compose.runtime.SnapshotStateKt__DerivedStateKt.observeDerivedStateRecalculations(DerivedState.kt:336)
        at androidx.compose.runtime.SnapshotStateKt.observeDerivedStateRecalculations(Unknown Source:1)
        at androidx.compose.runtime.ComposerImpl.doCompose(Composer.kt:3228)
        at androidx.compose.runtime.ComposerImpl.recompose$runtime_release(Composer.kt:3193)
        at androidx.compose.runtime.CompositionImpl.recompose(Composition.kt:753)
        at androidx.compose.runtime.Recomposer.performRecompose(Recomposer.kt:1008)
        at androidx.compose.runtime.Recomposer.access$performRecompose(Recomposer.kt:125)
        at androidx.compose.runtime.Recomposer$runRecomposeAndApplyChanges$2$2.invoke(Recomposer.kt:533)
        at androidx.compose.runtime.Recomposer$runRecomposeAndApplyChanges$2$2.invoke(Recomposer.kt:502)
        at androidx.compose.ui.platform.AndroidUiFrameClock$withFrameNanos$2$callback$1.doFrame(AndroidUiFrameClock.android.kt:34)
        at androidx.compose.ui.platform.AndroidUiDispatcher.performFrameDispatch(AndroidUiDispatcher.android.kt:109)
        at androidx.compose.ui.platform.AndroidUiDispatcher.access$performFrameDispatch(AndroidUiDispatcher.android.kt:41)
        at androidx.compose.ui.platform.AndroidUiDispatcher$dispatchCallback$1.doFrame(AndroidUiDispatcher.android.kt:69)
        at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:919)
        at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:729)
        at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:661)
        at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:907)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:790)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6549)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:451)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:888)
```

And From the point the App crashed I got this error on LOGCAT;

```
2022-10-12 21:40:36.758 5964-5964/? E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.think_healthy.keto, PID: 5964
    java.util.NoSuchElementException: Collection contains no element matching the predicate.
        at com.think_healthy.keto.model.SuccessInfoModel.getSuccessInfo(SuccessInfoModel.kt:120)
        at com.think_healthy.keto.ui.screens.success.SuccessInfoScreenKt.SuccessInfoDetails(SuccessInfoScreen.kt:39)
        at com.think_healthy.keto.ui.screens.success.SuccessInfoScreenKt.DisplaySuccessInfo(SuccessInfoScreen.kt:83)
        at com.think_healthy.keto.ui.screens.success.SuccessInfoScreenKt.SuccessInfoScreen(SuccessInfoScreen.kt:31)
        at com.think_healthy.keto.ComposableSingletons$KetoNavHostKt$lambda-3$1.invoke(KetoNavHost.kt:75)
        at com.think_healthy.keto.ComposableSingletons$KetoNavHostKt$lambda-3$1.invoke(KetoNavHost.kt:69)
        at androidx.compose.runtime.internal.ComposableLambdaImpl.invoke(ComposableLambda.jvm.kt:116)
        at androidx.compose.runtime.internal.ComposableLambdaImpl.invoke(ComposableLambda.jvm.kt:34)
        at androidx.navigation.compose.NavHostKt$NavHost$4$2.invoke(NavHost.kt:163)
        at androidx.navigation.compose.NavHostKt$NavHost$4$2.invoke(NavHost.kt:162)
        at androidx.compose.runtime.internal.ComposableLambdaImpl.invoke(ComposableLambda.jvm.kt:107)
        at androidx.compose.runtime.internal.ComposableLambdaImpl.invoke(ComposableLambda.jvm.kt:34)
        at androidx.compose.runtime.CompositionLocalKt.CompositionLocalProvider(CompositionLocal.kt:228)
        at androidx.compose.runtime.saveable.SaveableStateHolderImpl.SaveableStateProvider(SaveableStateHolder.kt:84)
        at androidx.navigation.compose.NavBackStackEntryProviderKt.SaveableStateProvider(NavBackStackEntryProvider.kt:60)
        at androidx.navigation.compose.NavBackStackEntryProviderKt.access$SaveableStateProvider(NavBackStackEntryProvider.kt:1)
        at androidx.navigation.compose.NavBackStackEntryProviderKt$LocalOwnersProvider$1.invoke(NavBackStackEntryProvider.kt:52)
        at androidx.navigation.compose.NavBackStackEntryProviderKt$LocalOwnersProvider$1.invoke(NavBackStackEntryProvider.kt:51)
        at androidx.compose.runtime.internal.ComposableLambdaImpl.invoke(ComposableLambda.jvm.kt:107)
        at androidx.compose.runtime.internal.ComposableLambdaImpl.invoke(ComposableLambda.jvm.kt:34)
        at androidx.compose.runtime.CompositionLocalKt.CompositionLocalProvider(CompositionLocal.kt:228)
        at androidx.navigation.compose.NavBackStackEntryProviderKt.LocalOwnersProvider(NavBackStackEntryProvider.kt:47)
        at androidx.navigation.compose.NavHostKt$NavHost$4.invoke(NavHost.kt:162)
        at androidx.navigation.compose.NavHostKt$NavHost$4.invoke(NavHost.kt:141)
        at androidx.compose.runtime.internal.ComposableLambdaImpl.invoke(ComposableLambda.jvm.kt:116)
        at androidx.compose.runtime.internal.ComposableLambdaImpl.invoke(ComposableLambda.jvm.kt:34)
        at androidx.compose.animation.CrossfadeKt$Crossfade$5$1.invoke(Crossfade.kt:133)
        at androidx.compose.animation.CrossfadeKt$Crossfade$5$1.invoke(Crossfade.kt:128)
        at androidx.compose.runtime.internal.ComposableLambdaImpl.invoke(ComposableLambda.jvm.kt:107)
        at androidx.compose.runtime.internal.ComposableLambdaImpl.invoke(ComposableLambda.jvm.kt:34)
        at androidx.compose.animation.CrossfadeKt.Crossfade(Crossfade.kt:142)
        at androidx.compose.animation.CrossfadeKt.Crossfade(Crossfade.kt:73)
        at androidx.navigation.compose.NavHostKt.NavHost(NavHost.kt:141)
        at androidx.navigation.compose.NavHostKt.NavHost(NavHost.kt:67)
        at com.think_healthy.keto.KetoNavHostKt.KetoNavHost(KetoNavHost.kt:22)
        at com.think_healthy.keto.ComposableSingletons$MainActivityKt$lambda-2$1$2.invoke(MainActivity.kt:54)
        at com.think_healthy.keto.ComposableSingletons$MainActivityKt$lambda-2$1$2.invoke(MainActivity.kt:53)
        at androidx.compose.runtime.internal.ComposableLambdaImpl.invoke(ComposableLambda.jvm.kt:116)
        at androidx.compose.runtime.internal.ComposableLambdaImpl$invoke$1.invoke(ComposableLambda.jvm.kt:127)
        at androidx.compose.runtime.internal.ComposableLambdaImpl$invoke$1.invoke(ComposableLambda.jvm.kt:127)
        at androidx.compose.runtime.RecomposeScopeImpl.compose(RecomposeScopeImpl.kt:145)
```

Answer (score 1):

Can you also upload error report when the app stops

Comment: please what error report are you talking about? And How do I get it?

Comment: debug your app and in logcat after app crash there will come some error lines in red color copy and paste it here

Comment: Thanks Syed I've Added Both Logcat and Run errors.

Comment: Edwin most probably the error is when you are passing data from one compose view to other, please check and get some info how to pass object from one composable to other